# how to set background image in submit button?

Tags: css, xhtml

how to set background image in submit button?

I have to use a image in place of regular submit button? which way would be best in xhtml/css?

Button should look same in all main browsers including IE6,IE7

Answer (score 39):

The way I usually do it, is with the following css:

```
div#submitForm input {
  background: url("../images/buttonbg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

and the markup:

```
<div id="submitForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>
```

If things look different in the various browsers I implore you to use a reset style sheet which sets all margins, padding and maybe even borders to zero.

Comment: I appreciate this is an old post now and guessing @Pratik didn't experience any issues, but I stumbled across this and couldn't help but notice the way you're selecting the submit input element here. You're selecting the global `input` element within the submitForm `<div>` therefore the style would be applied to elements such as `<input type="text">`. I'd consider setting a class against the submit input or using `input[type="submit"]` to select the button.

Answer (score 9):

```
.button {
    border: none;
    background: url('/forms/up.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically one would use one (or more) image tags, maybe in combination with setting div background images in css to act as the submit button. The actual submit would be done in javascript on the click event.

A [tutorial](http://cssbutton.com/forms/) on the subject.

Comment: The domain name at this link has expired.

Comment: You probably don't want a 12 year old css tutorial anyways, @Jordan

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 4):

i do it like this
cover button and the middle  image that

```
<button><img src="foldername/imagename" width="30px" height= "30px"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
background-image:url('url of your image') 10px 10px no-repeat
```

Comment: `background` is the shorthand to set multiple background properties at once.  `background-image` is just to set the url.