# Why won't type image work?

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to use a type="image" for a submit button. Not it is not working.

```
<input type="image" SRC="http://bin.xxx/images/free_download_continue.png" name="method_free" value="Free Download">
```

will not work for

```
<input type="submit" name="method_free" value="<TMPL_VAR lang_free_download>">
```

When I do this I http://jsfiddle.net/DXBgp/ get an error

but when I do this http://jsfiddle.net/EFjbx/ it works

Comment: Can you inline the jsFiddle code in your question? That way your question will be useful to others even if jsFiddle goes down within a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you got them mixed up, http://jsfiddle.net/DXBgp/ works and http://jsfiddle.net/EFjbx/ doesn't, correct ?

Check out this question at: [how to set background image in submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button). You should just be able to add a background image using CSS on the button.

Comment: What do you mean by "old button" ? Can you send a JSFiddle, or maybe explain in a little more detail what you mean by "old button" ? Do you mean the button with the ugly gray background ?

Comment: I manage to get rid of the word but the click area is to small. How can I make the area bigger and put it behind the image? http://jsfiddle.net/csV9X/

Comment: You would specify a width and a height in CSS? I.e. {width:100px;height:30px}. That is, if I understood you correctly

Comment: And the "left over" button is .. ? Do you mean you would need to delete the html tag that you had before? can you post a link to a screenshot or something like that ?