# Add image in a button

Tags: css

I try to make a button which text is `"Buy Now!"` but i want to `display small image` with this. Image in my `images/Buy-icon`. Please tell what wrong with it?
**my CSS**:

```
#submit
{       
  background-color: #ffb94b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fddb6f), to(#ffb94b));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);

 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;

  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;    

   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #d69e31 #e3a037 #d5982d #e3a037;

   float: left;
   height: 35px;
   padding: 0;
   width: 120px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica;
   color: #8f5a0a;
}

#submit:hover,#submit:focus
{       
  background-color: #fddb6f;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffb94b), to(#fddb6f));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);
}   

#submit:active 
{       
outline: none;

 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;        
}

#submit::-moz-focus-inner
{
 border: none;
}

#actions a
{
color: #3151A2;    
float: right;
line-height: 35px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#submit.buy_icon
{
  background-image:url("../images/Buy-icon.png");
  float: left;
}
```

In my **HTML**:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now!" id="submit" class="buy_icon"/>
```

But Buy Now button is successfully come only image is not come with it. What can I do? Please suggest.

Comment: used to this background-image:url("../images/Buy-icon.png");  addurl in "your image url"

Comment: might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button

Comment: try to increase the width of your button or increase the padding left/right see if that will work..

Comment: check to my updated anser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used to this  `#submit.buy_icon`

**as like this**

```
  #submit.buy_icon
    {
    background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPfZp.jpg?s=32&g=1");
background-position:right 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:32px;
border-width: 0;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    }
```

becuse you have define your `css` `#submit` css now `id` is more powerfull `class` than define

id and class in your css

```
#submit.buy_icon
```

### ------------

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/r3NmN/7/)**

Comment: Now image is coming but button goes smaller & black.

Comment: i want to float it in left & i added it but it doesn't. see above code.

Comment: can u provide me fiddle me

Comment: what? i don't understand !!

Comment: Do you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/r3NmN/2/  if now than please show me result images of your problum

Comment: where put my image in fiddle??

Comment: @SomnathKayal it's just example

Comment: i add the output above. see it.

Comment: Now used to background-position and background-repeat as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/r3NmN/5/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing `quotes` from the `background-image` and you need `!important` to ovveride the default behaviour:

```
.buy_icon
{
background-image:url('../images/Buy-icon.png')  !important;
width:32px;
height:32px;
border-width: 0;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ph6Wt/

Comment: i use it, but same thing happen.

Comment: @SomnathKayal - use !important

Answer (score 0):

The background you have defined for #submit is taking precedence over what you have defined for .buy_icon

Add !important after the background-image property in .buy_icon and it might help

Comment: I get the image But it always float right. how to solve it? Please check edit ate code above.