# Cant get a button to display on web page

Tags: html, css, button

Probably easy this but been scratching my head why it doesn't work for a while now.

I have a jpg image I want to use as a button and some text I want to be displayed on it.  I am trying to do this in html and css(2.1).

The html is:

```
<a href="page2.aspx" class="dash_button">Some Text</a>
```

The CSS is:

```
a.dash_button
{
   display:block;
   width:559px;
   height:55px;
   text-align:left;
   line-height:55px;
   background:transparent url("./images/dashboard_button.jpg") no-repeat;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:Blue;
}
```

from all the posts I have read this should work.  I am using VS2010 and testing in IE10

Comment: Please ignore the ` characters.  Also I should say the web page shows the link but no button.

Comment: is this path "./images/dashboard_button.jpg" correct for the button? Maybe try "~/images/dashboard_button.jpg"?

Comment: tried that and nope, has no effect

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set background image in submit button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button)

Comment: "../images/dashboard_button.jpg"

Comment: PW Kad, thanks that worked.  Can you explain why?

Comment: Tried using the button tags like <button><a href="#">Submit</a></button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your image path and checkout the css style

a.dash_button

```
{
display:block;
width:559px;
height:55px;
text-align:left;
line-height:55px;
background:url("../images/dashboard_button.jpg") no-repeat transparent;
text-decoration:none;
color:#3399cc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use and input button and use CSS to make it look how you want it to look? Not an answer, just a suggestion. I think it would be simpler to do that.