# HTML/CSS Position icon above text

Tags: html, css

Currently i have a lot of back buttons on my page:

```
<input type="button" id="Back" value="Back" onclick="back();" class="backButton">
```

I need to add icon to it to look something like this:

[image]

- First how do I add icon above text and aligne them centrally.
- And second is it possible to do it using only CSS. ( if not with only a minor modifications to HTML )

Thx in advance.

Comment: It is possible with CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: use the *cross image* as `background-image` and use `background-position`, further you've to play with `padding` and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes it's possible - http://jsfiddle.net/zusga3no/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NnXex/236/ is that what you want?

Comment: you can add the background image, see the link below:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button>

Answer (score 6):

> I need to add icon to it to look something like this:
>
> First how do I add icon above text and align them centrally.

You should use `button` element for that. It exists for this very purpose (*custom styling and markup*). However, you need not to use a `background-image` for that. To be able to control everything via CSS, just make sure you have same markup for all the buttons you have and then control using classes.

**For example**:

*Markup*:

```
<button class="cancel">
    <i></i>
    <span>Cancel</span>
</button>
```

*CSS*:

```
button.cancel i::after {
    content: '\00d7'; display: block;
    font-size: 26px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; color: red;
}
```

Use the `after` psuedo-element on `i` (or `span` whatever) and depending on the class use the `content` property to insert your icon as text (glyph) which you can style as you want.

> And second is it possible to do it using only CSS. ( if not with only
>   a minor modifications to HTML )

This is very much possible, but cumbersome. I would not recommend this method, it is not worth the effort. You have been warned.

To use the existing `input` as-is without any change in the markup, you need to style the `input` itself and will have to use a `background-image` (*in fact two background images*). The `input` styling has a problem, that it loses its platform style as soon as you tinker with its style. So, you will lose the button like behaviour and Windows like button gradient and effects. You will have to replicate all that functionality via CSS.

**For example**:

*Markup*:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" data-value="Cancel" />
```

*CSS*:

```
input[type=button] {
    min-width: 72px; height: 64px; position: relative;
    display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 36px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Emoji_u274c.svg'), 
        linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #dfdfdf);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 4px, center center;
    background-size: 24px, auto;
    border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=button]:active {
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Emoji_u274c.svg'), 
        linear-gradient(#dfdfdf, #f5f5f5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 4px, center center; 
    background-size: 24px, auto;
    outline: 0px;
}
input[type=button]:focus { outline: 0px; }
```

The above code uses first `background-image` to show the icon, and second `background-image` to show the gradient (*like Windows platform style*). It uses `padding-top` to push the text down and `:active` state to set the behaviour of inverting the gradient when clicked. `:focus` state to remove the `outline`.

All this to mimic the behaviour of a `button`! It is much better to use `button` itself.

Here is a combined demo of both the techniques:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/yw7wmvwh/1/**

**Snippet**:

```css
button { 
    min-width: 72px; height: auto; 
    display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; 
}
button.ok i::after {
    content: '\2713'; display: block;
    font-size: 23px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; color: green;
}
button.cancel i::after {
    content: '\00d7'; display: block;
    font-size: 26px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; color: red;
}

input[type=button] {
    min-width: 72px; height: 64px; position: relative;
    display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 36px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Emoji_u274c.svg'), 
        linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #dfdfdf);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 4px, center center;
    background-size: 24px, auto;
    border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=button]:active {
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Emoji_u274c.svg'), 
        linear-gradient(#dfdfdf, #f5f5f5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 4px, center center; 
    background-size: 24px, auto;
    outline: 0px;
}
input[type=button]:focus { outline: 0px; }
```

```html
<button class="ok">
    <i></i>
    <span>Ok</span>
</button>
<button class="cancel">
    <i></i>
    <span>Cancel</span>
</button>
<hr/>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" data-value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 2):

just add your class to css file

```css
.backButton{
  background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/24/Delete.png) no-repeat;
  background-position:center top;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding:24px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Back" value="Back" onclick="back();" class="backButton">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

**HTML**

```css
button {
font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }

#rock {
  padding:10px;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Crystal_button_cancel.svg) top center ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 10%; 
}
```

```html
<button id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Cancle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button id="btnCancel" onClick="choose(1)">Cancel</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }

#btnCancel {
  padding:10px;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Crystal_button_cancel.png) top center ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 10%;
    border-radius : 20px;
}
```