# background image for input type submit into email

Tags: html, css, email

Is it possible to apply a CSS background-image to a input type submit , this html element is a part of email template

```
 <input type="submit" value="" style="border: none;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/moDdJsa.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding: 2px 8px;" />
```

but it didnt work it displayed in my gmail account as a button with no image can you help

Comment: Looking at this answer I think you can solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button

Comment: thanks , but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a background size for the image. If there is a dimension for the button, then you should resize the background image to that dimension.

Also, I suspect the image is being rendered, however, the `top left` positioning you have applied is only making only the top left part of the image render in the button.

Try applying a positioning of `center center` 
then  `background-size: width height;`

The resulting code should look something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="" style="border: none;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/moDdJsa.png') no-repeat center center;
    padding: 2px 8px; background-size: width height;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the size

```
   <input type="submit" value="" style="border: none;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/moDdJsa.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding: 2px 8px; width:656px;
      height:570px;" />
```

This works
https://jsfiddle.net/scmn8tgy/