# CSS btn - background image doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

my problem seems to be quite simple. I want to create the button which is png and has hover via .png also. I need this for email campaigns becouse Outlook doesn't understand some css attributes. 
I tried make it simple

```
    .button {
    border: none;
    background: url(/image1.png);
}
    .button:hover {
    border: none;
    background: url(/image2.png);
}
```

And everything is just white. Any help will be great :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button

Comment: If you are doing it for Outlook you need to inline the styles anyway

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! HTML for emails is painful, since many email clients (e.g. Gmail, Outlook) use html 3 (ish). To develop specifically for Outlook, you can view the email in Word, as they use the same rendering engine. as @CalvT stated, you'll need to do everything as inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

[according to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url), you should do it like that,

```
background: url("/image1.png");
```

```css
.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/teLso.jpg?s=48&g=1");
}
.button:hover {
    border: none;
    background: url("https://graph.facebook.com/160520007817300/picture?type=large");
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error, use the simple, or double quotes "" - '', **an example:**

```css
button{
  background: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/24/fe/e1/24fee13b4dc475c435984ab0aa1b8ecb.jpg');
  background-size: 500px 100px;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button> Example button </button>
```

Same with any of the other html elements.